# How to display multiple images as background?

Tags: css, html

I want to add more than 1 picture as my background but I don't know what I should do. I want the images to follow each other. I don't want to merge the images. as i slide down image should change with other image with this set of code.

html

```
<div id="bg">`    
 <img src="images/two.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

css

```
 #bg {
   position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}

 #bg img {
position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;}
```

Comment: different images sorry for mistake.

Comment: You want slider as background ?

Comment: not slider background ;; background like as 1 image ends other image follow it.

Comment: I think what the OP wants is that when one bg image stops another starts. That's not possible with the current structure & CSS. It would, I think, require multiple 'background' divs each with their own bg image

Comment: yep that i wants can u guide me for that

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [multiple background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

```
.myclass {
  background: background1, background 2, ..., backgroundN;
}
```

You can the use [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) and [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```
 .myclass{
  background: url(http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/resources/images/logos/firefox-48.png),
        linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),  rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)),
        url(http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/resources/images/patterns/flowers-pattern.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: bottom right, left, right;
}
```

**Update**

it looks like you are trying to set display: block on images

```css
#bg{

}

#bg img{display:block}
```

```html
<div id="bg">`    
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x350" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: yep multiple background images but it should follow the property which i defined in question.

Comment: can u suggest the edit in current code so that it works for that.

Comment: i am not that much expert just learning through adobe dream weaver.

Comment: and the code which you given is for to merge many images to form background. i want many pics follow each other as background don't want to merge them with same property specified.

Comment: should i just add display:block  in #bg img { }

Comment: it;s working in snippet but not in my page -: @Tambo

Answer (score 0):

`background: url(test.png), url(test2.png);` should fix your problem but if you want to achieve it via `img` tag you can do it like below but this will not solve your current problem;

```
<img src="image-src.png" srcset="image-1x.png 1x, image-2x.png 2x,
                                 image-3x.png 3x, image-4x.png 4x">
```

Comment: yep i think so 
also but it is not working with this set of code.

Comment: @VipinYadav can you create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net? Your requirement is not clear to me. Thanks

Comment: i am just looking for edit in this code like that as i slide down image changes

Comment: @VipinYadav add a snap or graphic for your desired output